# API to check whether OS X device is protected with the password

Tags: macos, authentication

I am looking for an API to check whether macBook is protected with a password.

I am aware of similar API on iOS:

```
 LAContext *laContext = [[LAContext alloc] init];
 BOOL passcodeSet = [laContext canEvaluatePolicy:LAPolicyDeviceOwnerAuthentication error: &authError];
```

Unfortunately, this always returns true when you set a password to empty and/or turn on auto-login. I checked with Apple and it's expected behavior.

Is there any other API which allows to get password status (directly or indirectly)?

**Update 1**

It looks like I am using a little bit improper terminology. I am trying to check whether the user account is protected by password (rather whole mac is protected by password). However, that being said it's almost the same thing for a majority of end-users who own macOS device and have just one active account on it.

Comment: Question doesn't make sense to me. Surely the machine is not protected by a password, rather the individual user accounts are? So are you trying to find if a user account has a password set?

Comment: Or are you talking about a firmware password?

Comment: @TheNextman You are right. The better way would be to say that a user account is protected by the password. I will edit my question. However, that being said. Majority of end-users, have pretty much one end-user account on their macOS computers.

Comment: I'd say that "Majority of end-users, have pretty much one end-user account" is a pretty dangerous assumption, so I hope you program logic doesn't depend on that being true :) That said, I'm not sure of any API that will let you retrieve this information. You can try playing with `dscl`, especially the `-authonly` argument (https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/dscl.1.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if there is any API on that but You may want to see the /etc/passwd file. The second field on your user indicates the password. If nothing is there you may have no password for your login. On the other hand, if you have an x on this field you have a password associated to it and it may be at the /etc/shadow file

Comment: also this can be useful too : https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Security/Conceptual/SecureCodingGuide/Articles/AccessControl.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002589-SW18